# Can't retrieve values of options from select tag JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

[JSbin demo](https://jsbin.com/nafuzifemi/edit?html,js,output)

I need to calculate days difference between two dates.  The `selecedIndex` seems to be working fine demonstrated by alert box. When I try to retrieve values of options from select tag, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I tried changing my option tag by putting different values and putting the value under different attr of option tag - not very successful...

Comment: JS could be wrong too but I'm clueless what to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sometimes use `myForm` with **upercase** and other times`myform` with **lowercase**, you have to chose one of them.

Replace your `recalcDateDiff()` function with the following and it will work :

**JS :**

```
function recalcDateDiff()
{
    var myForm = document.form1;

    alert("myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex = " + myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex);
    alert("myform.firstDay.options[myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex].value = " + myForm.firstDay.options[myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex].value);
    var firstDay = myForm.firstDay.options[myForm.firstDay.selectedIndex].value;
    alert("Did you make it here - after retrieving the value of firstDay?");
    var secondDay = myForm.secondDay.options[myForm.secondDay.selectedIndex].value;
    var firstMonth = myForm.firstMonth.options[myForm.firstMonth.selectedIndex].value;
    var secondMonth = myForm.secondMonth.options[myForm.secondMonth.selectedIndex].value;
    var firstYear = myForm.firstYear.options[myForm.firstYear.selectedIndex].value;
    var secondYear = myForm.secondYear.options[myForm.secondYear.selectedIndex].value;
    var firstDate = new Date(firstDay + " " + firstMonth + " " + firstYear);
    var secondDate = new Date(secondDay + " " + secondMonth + " " + secondYear);
    alert("secondDate.valueOf(): " + secondDate.valueOf() + "\nfirstDate.valueOf(): " + firstDate.valueOf());
    var daysDiff = (secondDate.valueOf() - firstDate.valueOf());
    daysDiff = Math.floor(Math.abs((((daysDiff/1000)/60)/60)/24));
    myForm.txtDays.value=daysDiff;
}
```

Just replacing `myform` with `myForm`. Do the work next time you have to check your browser console ;)

**[Your JsBin updated](https://jsbin.com/badoja/edit?html,js,output)**

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to post your code here, not elsewhere, to ensure the code lasts as long as the question.

As Zakaria has noted, you have an issue with capitalisation of the form name. However, the form name isn't required anyway if you pass a reference to the element calling the listener using *this*.

Also, you are also using a poor method of converting values in the form to a Date object. Do not construct a string and parse it, particularly one that isn't compliant with ECMA-262. It's far better to give the options suitable values (e.g. zero indexed month numbers) and use the Date constructor as it's meant to be used, e.g.

```
  <select name="firstMonth" onchange="recalcDateDiff(this)">
    <option value="0">Jan</option>
    <option value="1">Feb</option>
    <option value="2">Mar</option>
    <option value="3">Apr</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">Jun</option>
    <option value="6">Jul</option>
    <option value="7">Aug</option>
    <option value="8">Sep</option>
    <option value="9">Oct</option>
    <option value="10">Nov</option>
    <option value="11">Dec</option>
  </select>
```

You should make one option in each select selected by default. Browsers will generally select the first one, but may not.

The function to calculate the date difference can be as simple as:

```
function recalcDateDiff(el) {
  var f = el.form;
  var d0 = new Date(f.firstYear.value, f.firstMonth.value, f.firstDay.value);
  var d1 = new Date(f.secondYear.value, f.secondMonth.value, f.secondDay.value);
  f.txtDays.value = Math.round((d1 - d0) / 8.64e7);
}
```

Rounding the difference takes care of transitioning daylight saving boundaries (which your current code doesn't do when transitioning into daylight saving).

If you want to validate the date entered (e.g. 30 February) that takes an extra line, but your existing function doesn't do that so I haven't included it.